# Cannot install dlib on mac os X

Tags: python, dlib

I am following the instructions here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/

line by line, *except* for the line where python3 is installed. I made a virtual environment and inside the virtualenv, did these four lines:

```
$ pip install numpy
$ pip install scipy
$ pip install scikit-image
$ pip install dlib
```

Unlike the instructions, the last line took a few seconds, not 15 minutes. After the installation, I opened `ipython` and tried `import dlib`, and receive this message:

```
----> 1 from .dlib import *
      2 __version__ = "19.4.0"

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myname/Documents/camera-project/code/story-board/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmkl_rt.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/Documents/camera-project/code/story-board/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I assume this means `dlib` is not properly installed, but I am not sure what I did wrong?

Also, I should add that I do not have`anaconda` on my mac, so it cannot be the issue. However earlier today I did, and I could load `dlib` without an issue, presumably because I am running a version of python distributed by `anaconda`, and I assume `dlib` comes with `anaconda`. However the `X11` distributed by `anaconda` is broken so I had to remove `anaconda` completely from my system and start over.

## EDIT

This is the message I get after installing dlib "successfully":

```
    :/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Installing collected packages: dlib
Successfully installed dlib-19.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install the pakage cmake.

When I tried installing dlib on my Mac in a virtualenv just now, I got the error

```
running bdist_wheel
  running build
  error: Cannot find cmake, ensure it is installed and in the path.
  You can install cmake on OSX using `sudo brew install cmake`.
  You can also specify its path with --cmake parameter.
```

So I would recommend trying to install cmake with

```
brew install cmake
```

Comment: I already installed `cmake` though, as well as boost. and boost-python

Comment: Did you install cmake while in your virtualenv? Also are there any errorswhen you try running pip install dlib, or does it just seem to install really quickly?

Comment: no I installed `cmake, boost, boost-python` outside of the virtualenv. And I insalled dlib fine, it just installed really quickly. I edited the question above for the message I get after the fast install.

Comment: Hmm. Are you running the `from .dlib import * __version__ = "19.4.0"` code in a python2 environment? I'm perplexed because it seems like it's trying to find the image in python2.7, but it seems like you've done all the installs correctly.

Comment: So after I source into the virtualenv, and opened `ipython`, all I did was `import dlib`. And then the error popped up.

Comment: Shoot. Well, I guess I don't know much about ipython with dlib, but I would try running the import statement in python3. Also, I would try running `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/lib:` because it seems the error comes from `Library not loaded: @rpath/libmkl_rt.dylib`. When I looked that up online I found this: [Make runtest failure](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2320). Hope that works for you!